# Capture DropDownList Index Change event inside of grid View

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to capture the SelectedIndexChanged event for a drop down list I have put inside of a gridview control.  It posts back fine, but does not go into my SelectedIndexChanged event handler.   Here is my code

```
    DropDownList myddl;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.myGridview.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(myGridview_RowDataBound);
        myddl = new DropDownList();
        myddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(myddl_SelectedIndexChanged);
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            List<Team> teams = giveMeTeams();
            this.myGridview.DataSource = teams;
            this.myGridview.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

            BoundField col1 = new BoundField();
            col1.DataField = "Name";
            this.myGridview.Columns.Add(col1);

            BoundField col2 = new BoundField();
            col2.DataField = "Sport";
            this.myGridview.Columns.Add(col2);

            BoundField col3 = new BoundField();
            col3.DataField = "Status";
            this.myGridview.Columns.Add(col3);

            this.myGridview.DataBind();
        }
    }

    void myGridview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        myddl = new DropDownList();
        myddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(myddl_SelectedIndexChanged);
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        items.Add("good");
        items.Add("bad");
        myddl.DataSource = items;
        myddl.AutoPostBack = true;
        myddl.DataBind();
        e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(myddl);
    }

    void myddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string temp = "In Here";  //neve hits this code
    }

    private List<Team> giveMeTeams()
    {
        Teams teams = new Teams();
        teams.Add(new Team("RedWings", "Hockey", "good"));
        teams.Add(new Team("Lions", "Football", "bad"));
        teams.Add(new Team("Packers", "Football", "good"));
        return teams;
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Edited based on Comments

I have tried as you suggested...and am still not capturing the post back.  here is my new code

```
        void myGridview_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList myddl = new DropDownList();
        myddl = new DropDownList();
        myddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(myddl_SelectedIndexChanged);
        myddl.ID = "MyID" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
        e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(myddl);
    }

    void myGridview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList myddl = e.Row.FindControl("MyID" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()) as DropDownList;
        //myddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(myddl_SelectedIndexChanged);
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        items.Add("good");
        items.Add("bad");
        myddl.DataSource = items;
        myddl.DataMember = "Status";
        myddl.AutoPostBack = true;
        myddl.DataBind();
        e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(myddl);
    }
```

it is still not going into my myddl_SelectedIndexChanged() eventhandler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create that Dropdownlist in RowCreated of the Grid and assign an ID to it. Get the refrence to these Dropdowns in RowDataBound via `e.Row.FindControl("MyDropdownlistID")` and bound them to the Datasource. Create distinct Dropdownlist instances instead of referencing always the same

Comment: I updated the original question with my new code.  Still not working.  Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: @mikemurf22 : You don't have to append the RowIndex to the DDL's ID, it must only be unique inide of the GridViewRow(their NamingContainer). ASP.Net generates unique IDs automatically and you can find them in RowDataBound via `FindControl("MyID")`. But the main problem is that you are adding them again in RowDataBound.  They will be recreated on every PostBack in RowCreated. Remove the line `e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(myddl);`. You also have to nest your code in RowCreated and RowDatabound inside of `if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
}`

Comment: got it working.  I was still wrapping the DataBind() in the !Page.PostBack.  This was preventing the event to register on the postback.  Once i got that figured out things started to flow.  Thanks for youre help

Comment: @mikemurf22 - I'm facing a problem similar to what you had. Can you pls post your working code.