# Alert when cells values are changed in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a gridview with dropdown values and an update button in a page. Whenever user changes any value in dropdown and tries to navigate away from the page (paging) a confirm alert should pop up. If they click OK then it has to navigate to the selected index page and if cancel is clicked it has to stay on the same page. Is there anyway I can track the changed cell value and give an alert when user tries to do paging or move to another page without clicking update button in the page.

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332077/capture-dropdownlist-index-change-event-inside-of-grid-view) to add a dropdown in the gridview and on change event of the dropdown you can add a `boolean` value to a viewstate variable for example

> ViewState["IsDDChanged"] = true;

Then you can register the gridview's `PageIndexChanging` event and check if the value in the   viewstate is true or not and then you can register a javascript using a "RegisterStartupScript" or "RegisterClientScriptBlock". The link is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11098/Use-Call-RegisterStartUpScript-RegisterClientScrip) on how to register a javascript.

After registering the javascript you can set the viewstate to false either in the same event or through an ajax call from the registered javascript mentioned above depending on your requirement. This is important for it to work the next time. You can even cancel the paging event. The event and a good example is given in this link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindexchanging%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

These might give you a good direction.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

I had some time at hand so have done this small POC for you. **Copy the aspx and aspx.cs code in a separate project and check if this is what you need**

The following are the steps i have followed

1. Created `RowCreated` event and added dropdownlist using it
2. Used `PageIndexChanging` event and registered javascript using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`
3. Added a button and hid it
4. If dropdownlist has changed and page has changed then confirmation pop up. If confirmation is a yes call click event of button from javascript which in turn will do paging for the gridview else if no dropdownlist has changed then continue with normal paging

There are a few points which I have done and which you need to remember

1. At the `@Page` directive i have given `EnableEventValidation="false"`. This was required so that I can fire click event of the hidden button but this is not a good practice as it reduces security. For more secured way, you should go with `UpdatePanel` of `AJAX extensions`.
2. I used a click event of hidden button instead of JQuery AJAX as it needs a static method in code-behind and we will not be able to set the paging of gridview in a static method. Else you would need to send the object of gridview from AJAX call but that was too cumbersome for me.
3. `AutoPostBack` to `true` for the dropdownlist is extremely important without which your `selectedIndexChanged` event will not get fired. i.e. `ddlDesignation.AutoPostBack = true;`

**aspx**

> ```
> <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Grid_Practice.aspx.cs"
>     EnableEventValidation="false" Inherits="Practice_Web.Grid_Practice" %>
>
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
> <head id="Head1" runat="server">
>     <title></title>
>     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
>         function ConfirmUser(msg) {
>             if (confirm(msg)) {
>                 __doPostBack('Button1', 'OnClick');
>             }
>         }
>     </script>
> </head>
> <body>
>     <form id="form1" runat="server">
>     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server">
>     </asp:ScriptManager>
>     <div>
>         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" Style="display: none;" />
>         <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
>             AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated">
>             <PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last"
>                 NextPageText="Next" PreviousPageText="Prev" Position="TopAndBottom" />
>             <Columns>
>                 <asp:BoundField />
>             </Columns>
>         </asp:GridView>
>     </div>
>     </form>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

**aspx.cs**

```
namespace Practice_Web
{
    public partial class Grid_Practice : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //Dummy value for gridview
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Designation", typeof(String)));

                DataRow dr = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
                {
                    dr = dt1.NewRow();

                    dr[0] = "designation" + (i % 2);
                    dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
                }

                Session["dt"] = dt1;
                GridView1.DataSource = dt1;
                GridView1.DataBind();    
            }

        }

        protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            Session["NewPageIndex"] = e.NewPageIndex;
            var sessionVar = Session["dropdownChanged"];
            bool dropdownChanged = false;

            if (sessionVar != null)
                dropdownChanged = Convert.ToBoolean(Session["dropdownChanged"]);

            if (dropdownChanged)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Error", "ConfirmUser('Are u sure');", true);
            }
            else
            {
                ChangeGridPage();
            }
        }

        public void ChangeGridPage()
        {
            int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Session["NewPageIndex"]);
            GridView1.PageIndex = pageIndex;
            GridView1.DataSource = (Session["dt"] as DataTable);
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DropDownList ddlDesignation = new DropDownList();
                ddlDesignation.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlDesignation_SelectedIndexChanged);
                ddlDesignation.AutoPostBack = true;

                ddlDesignation.ID = "MyID" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();

                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Designation", typeof(String)));

                DataRow dr = null;
                dr = dt1.NewRow();
                dr[0] = "designation0";
                dt1.Rows.Add(dr);

                dr = dt1.NewRow();
                dr[0] = "designation1";
                dt1.Rows.Add(dr);

                ddlDesignation.DataSource = dt1;
                ddlDesignation.DataTextField = "Designation";
                ddlDesignation.DataValueField = "Designation";
                ddlDesignation.DataBind();
                ddlDesignation.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));

                ddlDesignation.SelectedValue = (Session["dt"] as DataTable).Rows[e.Row.RowIndex][0].ToString();

                e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(ddlDesignation);
            }
        }

        void ddlDesignation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["dropdownChanged"] = true;
            //other code here
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChangeGridPage();
        }
    }
}
```

**Hope this solves your problem**

Comment: Not sure how I am gonna follow this. Bit confused in which event I am gonna keep track of gridview dropdown changes and show an alert on paging.

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted your question. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: samar - I am really confused. Can you help me frame the code.

Comment: I suggest try implementing step by step what I said. If you are stuck just update your question with whatever you have implemented and comment under my answer. I will guide you further. :)

Comment: I have given a small POC code in my answer. Copy the aspx and aspx.cs code in a separate project and check if that is what you need.

Comment: Samar -That was great. So in Row_Created I am binding the dropdown values from DB?

Comment: Yes you are. I have added dummy values to a datatable which is bound to the dropdown just to make the example easy to understand. In reality the datatable will get filled by a call to the database. Making a call to the database inside row_created event will mean that the database will get hit on each row. It is better to fetch the values of the dropdown on page load (inside !IsPostBack), put it in session state and then use the session state on row created. I hope you are understanding what I am trying to say. If you dont then please comment, I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Samar - This works great for Page-indexing and within the page. But how can I alert if I change the dropdown values and navigate to other page.

Comment: In my solution I have used a session variable Session["dropdownChanged"] this will tell you that at least 1 dropdown has been changed. You can use this to check and give alert accordingly using "ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript"

Answer (score 0):

This may seem a long answer but it's extremely easy to apply.

As a temporary (Alternative but working) solution for this scenario, I've found this article in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagertemplate.aspx)  about creating you create your own PagerTemplate for the GridView. The pager will be in DropDownList, it's very interesting and will be more flexible to achieve your requirement, I modified in the code a little bit in order to achieve the requirement.

In your Markup, modify the GridView to be like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridUsers" runat="server"  ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    OnDataBound="CustomersGridView_DataBound"
HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" >
 <pagerstyle forecolor="Blue"
  backcolor="LightBlue"/>

<PagerTemplate>
  <table width="100%">                    
    <tr>                        
      <td style="width:70%">

        <asp:label id="MessageLabel"
          forecolor="Blue"
          text="Select a page:" 
          runat="server"/>
        <asp:dropdownlist id="PageDropDownList"
          onselectedindexchanged="PageDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged"  
        AutoPostBack="true"              
        onChange="if(!confirm('Continue without saving?! Data will be lost!'))return false;"
         runat="server"/>
      </td>   

      <td style="width:70%; text-align:right">

        <asp:label id="CurrentPageLabel"
          forecolor="Blue"
          runat="server"/>
      </td>

    </tr>                    
  </table>

</PagerTemplate> 
    <Columns>   
    <!-- columns -->
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Next, add the following function (I'm using VB.Net):

```
Protected Sub PageDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    ' Retrieve the pager row.
    Dim pagerRow As GridViewRow = gridUsers.BottomPagerRow

    'Retrieve the PageDropDownList DropDownList from the bottom pager row.
    Dim pageList As DropDownList = DirectCast(pagerRow.Cells(0).FindControl("PageDropDownList"), DropDownList)

    ' Set the PageIndex property to display that page selected by the user.
    gridUsers.PageIndex = pageList.SelectedIndex
    SelectData()
End Sub
```

Finally, add the following function:

```
 Protected Sub CustomersGridView_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        ' Retrieve the pager row.
        Dim pagerRow As GridViewRow = gridUsers.BottomPagerRow

        'Retrieve the PageDropDownList DropDownList from the bottom pager row.
        Dim pageList As DropDownList = DirectCast(pagerRow.Cells(0).FindControl("PageDropDownList"), DropDownList)

        Dim pageLabel As Label = DirectCast(pagerRow.Cells(0).FindControl("CurrentPageLabel"), Label)

        If pageList IsNot Nothing Then

            For i As Integer = 0 To gridUsers.PageCount

                Dim pageNumber As Integer = i + 1
                Dim item As New ListItem(pageNumber.ToString())


                If i = gridUsers.PageIndex Then

                    item.Selected = True
                End If

                pageList.Items.Add(item)
            Next

        End If

        If pageLabel IsNot Nothing Then  
            Dim currentPage As Integer = gridUsers.PageIndex + 1
            pageLabel.Text = "Page " + currentPage.ToString() + " of " + gridUsers.PageCount.ToString()

        End If
    End Sub
```

I'm sure it's not the best solution but it's interesting. Note that I've modified the DropDownList design and added the "OnChange" event which will do the client alert trick.

However, there's still one more thing you'll need to figure out which is return the old page number in the DropDownList if the user cancelled the postback, I guess you'll just create a javascript function to achieve that somehow.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But the dropdown is used inside Pagertemplate not inside columns. How can i do that?

Comment: This dropdownlist is different than the dropdownlist in columns.  the dropdownlist is an alterantive way to view page numbers, instead of the default page numbers in the gridview, _this dropdownlist will contain all the pages numbers_ and _when you click on the a different page number it will show you the alert before moving to another page_. This is an alternative way to solve your problem so I suggest you try with Samar's answer first as it's appear to be a more elegant answer. Just keep this answer as an alternative solution.